# two dots on a line that are the same distance from plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Find two dots on a line that is determined by plane cross:

$5x + 3y - 1 = 0$

$2x + 3z + 5 = 0$

That are the same length from two planes $3x + 3y - 2 = 0$ and $4x + y + z + 4 = 0$.

I found a line equation:

$x = -1 + 3t$

$y =  2 - 5t$

$z = -1 - 2t$

Now I don't know how to find two dots that are the same length from those two planes.

My another question is how it is possible that there are two dots on a line that is the same distance from two planes. I thought there is only one.

Comment: You're working in 3d so you can try to visualize it in real life. Get a piece of paper, and pick a direction and point that way. See if you can find two points which are equally close to the plane. You're right that there is a single closest point, but for any other distance to the plane, hopefully you'll be able to see there are two points which are both this distance to the plane.

Comment: okay thank you! But do you know how to find those two dots?

Comment: I would start by coming up with an equation which gives the distance from any point on the line to the plane. I.e. a function $d(t)$ which gives the distance from $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ to the plane. Now, for a given distance $d_0$, try to solve $d(t) = d_0$ for $t$.

Comment: It seems to me that there is only one point on the line that is equidistant from the two planes.

Comment: @DougM The line isn’t parallel to either angle bisector, so there are two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points that are equidistant from a pair of non-parallel planes lie on their two angle bisectors, which are themselves planes. Work out their equations and then find the intersection of the given line with the bisectors.